# How Jackson taking module beans automatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I am having below class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Module jdk8Module() {
        return new Jdk8Module();
    }

    @Bean
    public Module guavaModule() {
        return new GuavaModule();
    }
}
```

Here these two beans automatically registered in jackson ObjectMapper. How it's registered this modules automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by the Spring Boot [`JacksonAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.9.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.html) class.

As the javadoc says:

> Auto configuration for Jackson. The following auto-configuration will get applied:
>
> - an `ObjectMapper` in case none is already configured.
> - a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` in case none is already configured.
> - **auto-registration for all `Module` beans with all `ObjectMapper` beans** (including the defaulted ones).

Answer (score 2):

Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are automatically registered with the auto-configured Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application. so it should be enough to define a bean and it will be automatically registered in jackson ObjectMapper.